# Can't cast object to array of custom class

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following servlet code:

```
    SearchResult[] basicResults = AuctionSearchClient.basicSearch(search, numToSkip, numToReturn);

    request.setAttribute("search_result", basicResults);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/search.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Then in my search.jsp file I have the following code:

```
SearchResult[] searchResult = (SearchResult[])request.getAttribute("search_result");
```

However I am getting an error saying:

> SearchResult cannot be resolved to a type

request is an object of type HttpServletRequest.
Why am I getting this casting error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a Java class in JSP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717376/how-to-call-a-java-class-in-jsp-file)

Comment: Thank you, should I remove this post?